# Symfony 5: apply template to all fields of specific custom form type

Tags: php, symfony, yaml, twig, symfony5

I have created custom form type field and I don't want apply custom theme for this field like this: `{% form_theme form.test 'custom_fields/datalist.html.twig' %}` every time when I use this field.

Is there any way to apply this template to all fields with this type by adding something to twig config, etc?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I added this to my twig.yaml:

```
form_themes: [
        'custom_fields/datalist.html.twig'
]
```

In template I set correct block prefix: {% block datalist_widget %}
And now for every DatalistType field applied custom template.